# duplicates itens in csv to a pythonic dict or json

Tags: python, json, csv, dictionary

I have done a lot of searching here for something that could help me and have found a few things that helped for an initial json.

I have a csv in this format:

```
STUDENT_ID,FULL_NAME,COURSE_CODE,COURSE_NAME,DISCIPLINE_NAME
1,STUDENT_ONE,GAM,GESTAO AMBIENTAL,BIOQUÍMICA AMBIENTAL
1,STUDENT_ONE,GAM,GESTAO AMBIENTAL,GEOPROCESSAMENTO APLICADO À GESTÃO AMBIENTAL
2,STUDENT_TWO,COM,COMERCIO,FUNDAMENTOS DO COMÉRCIO EXTERIOR
2,STUDENT_TWO,COM,COMERCIO,PROJETO INTEGRADOR II
2,STUDENT_TWO,COM,COMERCIO,LÍNGUA PORTUGUESA III
2,STUDENT_TWO,COM,COMERCIO,QUÍMICA II
2,STUDENT_TWO,COM,COMERCIO, FÍSICA I
2,STUDENT_TWO,COM,COMERCIO,EDUCAÇÃO FÍSICA I
2,STUDENT_TWO,COM,COMERCIO,MATEMÁTICA III
2,STUDENT_TWO,COM,COMERCIO,SOCIOLOGIA III
2,STUDENT_TWO,COM,COMERCIO,FUNDAMENTOS DE CONTABILIDADE APLICADOS AO COMÉRCIO E SERVIÇOS
2,STUDENT_TWO,COM,COMERCIO,BIOLOGIA III
2,STUDENT_TWO,COM,COMERCIO,FILOSOFIA III
3,STUDENT_THREE,TME,TEORIAS E METODOLOGIAS DA EDUCAÇÃO,TRABALHO DE CONCLUSÃO DO CURSO
```

I was able to generate a json for COD_CURSO with the code below:

```py
temp1 = {}

for student in out:
    curso = student.pop("COD_CURSO")
    if not temp1.get(curso, None):
        temp1[curso] = []
    temp1[curso].append(student)
```

The json looked as follows:

```json
{
  "GAM": [
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 1,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_ONE",
      "COURSE_NAME": "GESTAO AMBIENTAL",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "BIOQUÍMICA AMBIENTAL"
    },
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 1,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_ONE",
      "COURSE_NAME": "GESTAO AMBIENTAL",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "GEOPROCESSAMENTO APLICADO À GESTÃO AMBIENTAL"
    }
  ],
  "COM": [
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 2,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_TWO",
      "COURSE_NAME": "COMERCIO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "FUNDAMENTOS DO COMÉRCIO EXTERIOR"
    },
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 2,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_TWO",
      "COURSE_NAME": "COMERCIO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "PROJETO INTEGRADOR II"
    },
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 2,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_TWO",
      "COURSE_NAME": "COMERCIO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "LÍNGUA PORTUGUESA III"
    },
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 2,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_TWO",
      "COURSE_NAME": "COMERCIO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "QUÍMICA II"
    },
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 2,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_TWO",
      "COURSE_NAME": "COMERCIO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": " FÍSICA I"
    },
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 2,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_TWO",
      "COURSE_NAME": "COMERCIO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "EDUCAÇÃO FÍSICA I"
    },
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 2,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_TWO",
      "COURSE_NAME": "COMERCIO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "MATEMÁTICA III"
    },
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 2,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_TWO",
      "COURSE_NAME": "COMERCIO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "SOCIOLOGIA III"
    },
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 2,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_TWO",
      "COURSE_NAME": "COMERCIO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "FUNDAMENTOS DE CONTABILIDADE APLICADOS AO COMÉRCIO E SERVIÇOS"
    },
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 2,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_TWO",
      "COURSE_NAME": "COMERCIO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "BIOLOGIA III"
    },
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 2,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_TWO",
      "COURSE_NAME": "COMERCIO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "FILOSOFIA III"
    }
  ],
  "TME": [
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 3,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_THREE",
      "COURSE_NAME": "TEORIAS E METODOLOGIAS DA EDUCAÇÃO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "TRABALHO DE CONCLUSÃO DO CURSO"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to merge the duplicate students with their respective disciplines like as follow.

```json
{
  "GAM": [
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 1,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_ONE",
      "COURSE_NAME": "GESTAO AMBIENTAL",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": [
        "BIOQUÍMICA AMBIENTAL",
        "GEOPROCESSAMENTO APLICADO À GESTÃO AMBIENTAL"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "COM": [
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 2,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_TWO",
      "COURSE_NAME": "COMERCIO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": [
        "FUNDAMENTOS DO COMÉRCIO EXTERIOR",
        "PROJETO INTEGRADOR II",
        "LÍNGUA PORTUGUESA III",
        "QUÍMICA II",
        "FÍSICA I",
        "EDUCAÇÃO FÍSICA I",
        "MATEMÁTICA III",
        "SOCIOLOGIA III",
        "FUNDAMENTOS DE CONTABILIDADE APLICADOS AO COMÉRCIO E SERVIÇOS",
        "BIOLOGIA III",
        "FILOSOFIA III"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "TME": [
    {
      "STUDENT_ID": 3,
      "FULL_NAME": "STUDENT_THREE",
      "COURSE_NAME": "TEORIAS E METODOLOGIAS DA EDUCAÇÃO",
      "DISCIPLINE_NAME": "TRABALHO DE CONCLUSÃO DO CURSO"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea how I could do it?

Comment: How do you determine what a student is? I don't know the language your data is in, it's hard to tell from the field names.

Comment: I edit the language data and I determine the student by STUDENT_ID.

Comment: Could you give an example of the output your program should have? How should the data be presented after the merge?

Comment: @AkilanManivannan I put an example in the main post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's a great task to solve with python. You need to transform the data, and there are actually many ways how you can do it. A modern way might be to use pandas. [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) makes it really easy to read CSV data (`pd.read_csv('data.csv')`). You could then use something like "groupby" as explained in this [article on GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/concatenate-strings-from-several-rows-using-pandas-groupby/).

You can work it with just good old python, too. I present my idea in the following.

*(Note: "import data" is just the a dictionary containing the data that you have provided in your question / example as json.)*

```py
from typing import List
import pprint

from data import data


def transform_dict(data: List[dict]) -> dict:
    transformed_data = dict()
    for obj in data:

        current_student = obj['STUDENT_ID']

        new_structure = {
            current_student: {
                'STUDENT_ID': obj['STUDENT_ID'],
                'FULL_NAME': obj['FULL_NAME'],
                'COURSE_NAME': obj['COURSE_NAME'],
                'DISCIPLINE_NAME': [obj['DISCIPLINE_NAME']]
            }
        }

        if current_student not in transformed_data:
            transformed_data.update(new_structure)
            continue

        transformed_data[current_student]['DISCIPLINE_NAME'].append(obj['DISCIPLINE_NAME'])

    return transformed_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    solution = dict()
    for course, records in data.items():
        solution.update({course: transform_dict(records)})
    pprint.pprint(solution)
```

This will result into the following data:

```py
{'COM': {2: {'COURSE_NAME': 'COMERCIO',
             'DISCIPLINE_NAME': ['FUNDAMENTOS DO COMÉRCIO EXTERIOR',
                                 'PROJETO INTEGRADOR II',
                                 'LÍNGUA PORTUGUESA III',
                                 'QUÍMICA II',
                                 ' FÍSICA I',
                                 'EDUCAÇÃO FÍSICA I',
                                 'MATEMÁTICA III',
                                 'SOCIOLOGIA III',
                                 'FUNDAMENTOS DE CONTABILIDADE APLICADOS AO '
                                 'COMÉRCIO E SERVIÇOS',
                                 'BIOLOGIA III',
                                 'FILOSOFIA III'],
             'FULL_NAME': 'STUDENT_TWO',
             'STUDENT_ID': 2}},
 'GAM': {1: {'COURSE_NAME': 'GESTAO AMBIENTAL',
             'DISCIPLINE_NAME': ['BIOQUÍMICA AMBIENTAL',
                                 'GEOPROCESSAMENTO APLICADO À GESTÃO '
                                 'AMBIENTAL'],
             'FULL_NAME': 'STUDENT_ONE',
             'STUDENT_ID': 1}},
 'TME': {3: {'COURSE_NAME': 'TEORIAS E METODOLOGIAS DA EDUCAÇÃO',
             'DISCIPLINE_NAME': ['TRABALHO DE CONCLUSÃO DO CURSO'],
             'FULL_NAME': 'STUDENT_THREE',
             'STUDENT_ID': 3}}}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I have created a new key instead of using just the object: `{"COM": {3: data}}`. If you want to omit mapping the data to a student (`{"COM": data}`), you can do another transformation:

```py
def transform_again(data):
    transformed_data = dict()
    for obj in data:
        transformed_data.update(data[obj])
    return transformed_data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    solution = dict()
    for course, records in data.items():
        solution.update({course: transform_dict(records)})
    # pprint.pprint(solution)

    solution_2 = transform_again(solution['COM'])
    pprint.pprint(solution_2)
```

This will lead to:

```py
{'COURSE_NAME': 'COMERCIO',
 'DISCIPLINE_NAME': ['FUNDAMENTOS DO COMÉRCIO EXTERIOR',
                     'PROJETO INTEGRADOR II',
                     'LÍNGUA PORTUGUESA III',
                     'QUÍMICA II',
                     ' FÍSICA I',
                     'EDUCAÇÃO FÍSICA I',
                     'MATEMÁTICA III',
                     'SOCIOLOGIA III',
                     'FUNDAMENTOS DE CONTABILIDADE APLICADOS AO COMÉRCIO E '
                     'SERVIÇOS',
                     'BIOLOGIA III',
                     'FILOSOFIA III'],
 'FULL_NAME': 'STUDENT_TWO',
 'STUDENT_ID': 2}
```

And now you can start refactoring everything and make it more efficient. :) This was fun answering, I hope that my answer is helpful to you! Good luck.